# SQL Script File to Open More than One Worksheet

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to save a single SQL Script file so that when it re-opens it will open all my worksheets associated with this certain Script.

For Example: I have three worksheets open

First Sheet

```
SELECT * FROM USER
WHERE AGE < '21'
ORDER BY AGE DESC
```

Second Sheet

```
UPDATE USER SET CAN_DRINK = 'NO'
WHERE AGE < '21'
```

Third Sheet

```
DELETE FROM USER
WHERE AGE < '21'
AND CAN_DRINK = 'NO'
```

I want to save these in one SQL Script file that when you open it, it will open three worksheets rather than in one.

This is to avoid typing redundant queries that I would run often. This would load them all at once rather than open one script at a time.

I am aware that you can use semi-colons or highlight the script you want to use but I would like to see if it is possible to open up these multiple sheets.

I am not sure this is entirely possible but maybe there is something I am unaware of that does something similar.

Comment: Stored procedures are a very good way to avoid typing redundant queries that you would run often.